# permanent strongholds for warlocks

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, warlock, sorcerer, bard

In *Xanathar's Guide to Everything*, there are a series of spells, *Druid Grove*, *Temple of the Gods*, and *Mighty Fortress* for druids, clerics, and wizards respectively. However, there is no equivalent I could find for the other full casters with access to higher-level spells (sorcerer. bard. and warlock), are there similar spells accessible for these classes?

Comment: An observation: These three classes are 'known' casters, while the other three are 'prepared' casters. Since these fortress spells would only be used rarely, maybe that could contribute to why one set has these spells while the other does not. That doesn't answer your question, but I thought it was noteworthy.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

#### Bards can pick any spell

The Bard has a feature called Magical Secrets:

> By 10th level, you have plundered magical knowledge from a wide spectrum of disciplines. Choose two spells from any classes, including this one. A spell you choose must be of a level you can cast, as shown on the Bard table, or a cantrip.
>
> The chosen spells count as bard spells for you and are included in the number in the Spells Known column of the Bard table.
>
> You learn two additional spells from any classes at 14th level and again at 18th level.

So the Bard can get any of the spells you listed.

#### Most warlocks are out of luck.

There just isn’t a way for a warlock to learn any of these spells.

#### Sorcerers and Genie Warlocks can improvise a permanent fortress.

The Sorcerer and Genie Warlock can learn the spell *wall of stone*:

> A nonmagical wall of solid stone springs into existence at a point you choose within range. The wall is 6 inches thick and is composed of ten 10-foot- by-10-foot panels. Each panel must be contiguous with at least one other panel. Alternatively, you can create 10-foot-by-20-foot panels that are only 3 inches thick.
>
> [...]
>
> If you maintain your concentration on this spell for its whole duration, the wall becomes permanent and can't be dispelled. Otherwise, the wall disappears when the spell ends.

Through a series of castings of *wall of stone* a sorcerer or Genie Warlock could improvise a permanent structure.

#### Ask your DM if you can have one of those spells in exchange for one on your list.

It doesn’t hurt to ask. The *Dungeon Master’s Guide* has some guidance in modifying spell lists:

> Modifying a class’s spell list usually has little effect on a character’s power but can change the flavor of a class significantly. In your world, paladins might not swear their oaths to ideals, but instead swear fealty to powerful sorcerers. To capture this story concept, you could build a new paladin spell list with spells meant to protect their masters, drawn from the sorcerer or wizard lists. Suddenly, the paladin feels like a different class.
>
> Be cautious when changing the warlock spell list. Since warlocks regain their spell slots after a short rest, they have the potential to use certain spells more times in a day than other classes do.

I’d say there wouldn’t be any issues letting a Warlock take one of these high level spells with their mystic arcanum, since the 6th level and higher spells learned this way are 1/day only.